# How to edit SSRS 2008R2 Reports in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: .net, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm a report writer who's been able to edit/update reports in Visual Studio 2008 (we use SSRS2008R2). I've just installed Visual Studio 2012 and when I go to convert my reports project it's not working as I appear to be missing a component.

Essentially - the project converts but in the solution explorer I see the message 'The application is not installed' under my project.

Beyond Visual Studio 2012 what else do I have to install to be able to edit rdl files in the visual designer like I could in Visual Studio 2008?

I have Visual Studio 2012 Premium + Expression Blend installed.

Comment: Looks like Microsoft released a patch for VS 2012 that lets you work on SSRS 2012 reports. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843

Comment: Working too in **VS2013** ? Or any dummy full source code sample ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

SSRS development functionality became available for [Visual Studio 2012 in March 2013](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/data-driver/2013/03/bids-templates-added-to-visual-studio-2012.aspx).

The [components needed for SSRS development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027) are as follows:

- [Download SSDT for Visual Studio 2012](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=274984)
- [Download SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843)
- [Download Data-Tier Application Framework (March 2013)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36842)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027     Here are some "update" packages and links.