# ReportViewer problems

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer

I've been trying to get a report running through Microsoft ReportViewer in Visual Studio 2012.  Here is my situation.

I have a report (.rdl file) that was originally created through Microsoft Reporting Services running on a SQL Server 2008 R2 server.

I originally tried moving it into a VB.NET project running through Visual Studio 2005, but when I converted the .rdl file to .rdlc and tried to bring it into the VS 2005, I could not view the .rdlc file in design time.  A while after that, I figured out that this was due to schema compatibility issues because of the fact that the report was created on a SQL Server 2008 server.

So then I tried creating a project through Visual Studio 2012 instead, which we also had in house.  This time I was successfull at being able to view the report in design time.  However after that, I ran into run time issues because I was using Version 8 of the Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms dll.  I believe that this was also due to a schema comaptibility issue

So now, I'm trying to move up to using a newer version of the Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms dll (Version 11).  When I remove the Version 8 and add the version 11 instead in my references, everything appears to be fine at first, no errors present.  However, when I try to build my project I get the many compile errors all over the place like the following:

Type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer' is not defined.

The wierdest part is that if I were to remove and re-add the reference, or check one of the Microsoft.Reporting references in the Imported namespace, all the errors go away.  But when I rebuild the project the errors come back, and I'm stuck.

I'm currently running the Microsoft .NET framework 4.5 on my computer, and I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 as my development platform.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,

Doug

Comment: Are you using a wizard to create report? Wizard messes things up. Also, have you added `using System.Windows.Forms;`

Comment: Also, have you included `using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;`

Comment: I've tried checking the namespace Microsoft.Reporting.Winform. Errors went away after that, but when I rebuilt, the errors came back.

Comment: Report was created originally on SQL Server Reporting Services, not sure if it was done using a Wizard or not because I wasn't the one who originally created it.  My task though is to move it from Running on the Server With reporting services (.rdl) to running locally through visual studio.

Comment: Also, the line of code that it is erroring on is as follows: Me.ReportViewer1 = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer I'm not sure that including a using statement will work in this case because I'm using the entire namespace when declaring my report viewer.  This is my first time using a blog, so please excuse me if I don't know how format my comments properly.

Comment: In your list of references in Solution Explorer, can you make sure Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms are present? Also make sure you have the using directives that I wrote above in each of your files

Comment: The MicroSoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll doesn't appear to be present in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\ReportViewer folder.  This was the folder that I retreived the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll from.

Comment: I'm really confused as to how a using statment is going to help me.  I believe that a using statement can only be called in functions or procedures.  I don't think it will remedy problem with a class level object declaration.  I've tried "Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms".  If you can provide a brief example as to how I should be using the "using" statement, that would be appreciated.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Please check the answer on this thread. That might help you. `using` directive is used as follows: `using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;` . Please let me know if you still have trouble. I will write it in a blog post and link it here.

Comment: I think we may be confusing what programming language I'm using here (VB.NET).  In VB.NET, I don't believe I can use the using directive outside of a procedure or function.  I tried putting the using directive recommended just before my class declaration, and also just inside of my class (both places outside of procedures), and both times I got compile errors.  Now VB.NET does allow me to use "Imports Microsoft.Reporting.Winforms" but that hasn't helped me with my ReportViewer errors either.

Comment: oh sorry I wasnt aware of that. Did you check theck the link I posted in the answer below?

Comment: Ok, I installed one of the downloads from the blog of your below link. The one I installed was the "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012", the following link, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843, and it did not appear to help at all. I also tried searching my C drive to see if it installed a new Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms.dll somewhere, but I could not find one. I'm still stuck with ReportViewer compile errors all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [How to edit SSRS 2008R2 Reports in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503976/how-to-edit-ssrs-2008r2-reports-in-visual-studio-2012)