# How to open rdl Created with Visual Studio 2008, in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to open an SSRS report that was created in Visual Studio 2008. I only have Visual Studio 2012, so I need to convert or upgrade the file.

I followed the instructions at this site, but I still don't get what I need.

[How to edit SSRS 2008R2 Reports in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503976/how-to-edit-ssrs-2008r2-reports-in-visual-studio-2012)

When I click on the rdl the file simply opens as an XML file in Visual Studio 2012. I need to be able to open it in design mode within the IDE. Does anyone know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you got the 2008 reporting project that contains the report?

Comment: If you're asking if I have a solution (a .sln) then no. I have one file. A .rdl file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the project file it can be quite tedious.

If the report is currently deployed to an existing reporting services server you can do the following.

1. create a new vs2012 reports project
2. download the data sources from the report server an import them into your project.
3. import the report into your project and try opening it
4. if it complains of missing datasets you will need to examine the report xml to find the datasets so that you can recreate them.

If all you have is the report then

1. You need to create a new reporting project using VS2012
2. you then need to import your report into the project.
3. you will have to study the xml of the report in order to determine
   the data source name(s)
4. you will need to recreate the data source(s) in your project
5. you may also have to recreate the datasets used in the report
   again you can find details in the report xml.